# button functionality for selected items JS

Tags: javascript, html, function, select, button

I am doing To Do List app. After the user-input, information is displayed in the table. My goal is to mark the selected item from that table and apply some button functionalities to them ( mark them completed, important, or remove the item). However, I figured out the selecting part, but can not make the button work.

here is the printscreen
!(https://ibb.co/dtZ11KD)

HTML

```
<strike> 

    <form>
            <div>
                <label for="todo-date">Date</label>
                <input type="date" class="todo-date" id="todo-date">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="todo-task">Task</label>
                <input type="text" class="todo-input" id="todo-task">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="todo-responsible">Who is responsible</label>
                <input type="text" class="todo-responsible" id="todo-responsible">
            </div>
            <div>
                <button class="todo-button" id="todo-button">
                    <i class="fas fa-plus-square"></i>
            </button>
            </div>
    </form>
    <table class="content-table" id="content-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Task</th>
                <th>Responsible</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody  id="tbl-result" class="tblResult">
            <tr class="tbr-click">
                <td>Date</td>
                <td>Task</td>
                <td>Responsible</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <section>
        <div>
            <button class="complete-btn" id="complete-btn">
                <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button class="imp-btn" id="imp-btn">
                <i class="fas fa-trash"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button class="trash-btn" id="trash-btn">
                <i class="fas fa-exclamation"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
    </section>
 


    <script src="app.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
</strike>


'''
// Selectors

    const toDoDate = document.getElementById('todo-date');
    const toDoInput = document.getElementById('todo-task');
    const toDoResp = document.getElementById('todo-responsible');
    const toDoButton = document.getElementById('todo-button');
    const completeBtn = document.getElementById('complete-btn');
    const impBtn = document.getElementById('imp-btn');
    const trashBtn = document.getElementById('trash-btn');
    const tblResult = document.getElementById('tbl-result');
    const cntTable = document.getElementById('content-table');
    const cntCells = document.getElementsByTagName('td');

    // Event listeners
    toDoButton.addEventListener('click', addToDo);
    completeBtn.addEventListener('click', addComplete);
    impBtn.addEventListener('click', markImp);
    trashBtn.addEventListener('click', deletBtn);


// Functions


function addToDo(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    let newRow = tblResult.insertRow(0);
    let cell1 = newRow.insertCell(0);
    let cell2 = newRow.insertCell(1);
    let cell3 = newRow.insertCell(2);

    cell1.innerHTML = toDoDate.value;
    cell2.innerHTML = toDoInput.value;
    cell3.innerHTML = toDoResp.value;
    
    selectRow();
}

function selectRow () {
    for (i=0; i < cntCells.length; i++) {
        cntCells[i].onclick = function () {
            let indexSel = this.parentNode.rowIndex;
            let rowsNotSelected = cntTable.getElementsByTagName('tr');
            for (let row = 0; row < rowsNotSelected.length; row++) {
                rowsNotSelected[row].style.backgroundColor = "";
                rowsNotSelected[row].classList.remove('selected');
            }
            let rowSelected = cntTable.getElementsByTagName('tr')[indexSel];
            rowSelected.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
            rowSelected.classList.add('selected'); 
        }
    }
}


function addComplete () {
    if (rowSelected.classList.contains('selected')) {
        console.log('hey');
    } else {
        console.log('no');
    }
 }

 function markImp () {
    console.log('Mark');
 }

 function deletBtn () {
    console.log('DELETE');
 }
'''
```

Buttons are working, the function addCompleted is not. Any kind of help or advice would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your `rowSelected` global for general access.. Modify as below

```
let rowSelected;
function selectRow () {
for (i=0; i < cntCells.length; i++) {
        cntCells[i].onclick = function () {
        let indexSel = this.parentNode.rowIndex;
        let rowsNotSelected = cntTable.getElementsByTagName('tr');
        for (let row = 0; row < rowsNotSelected.length; row++) {
            rowsNotSelected[row].style.backgroundColor = "";
            rowsNotSelected[row].classList.remove('selected');
        }
       //do not re-declare rowSelected, just assign;
        rowSelected = cntTable.getElementsByTagName('tr')[indexSel];
        rowSelected.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
        rowSelected.classList.add('selected');
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember when declaring a variable inside a function it's scope is inside that function. you cannot access it outside that method. Your mistake is you trying to access 'rowSelected' variable from another function which is not accessible to this variable. make this variable global one so you can access. Please refer JS variable scope.

[refer this variable scopes doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var)

I corrected your code. please check

```js
let rowSelected
        var init = () => {
        
            const toDoDate = document.getElementById('todo-date');
            const toDoInput = document.getElementById('todo-task');
            const toDoResp = document.getElementById('todo-responsible');
            const toDoButton = document.getElementById('todo-button');
            const completeBtn = document.getElementById('complete-btn');
            const impBtn = document.getElementById('imp-btn');
            const trashBtn = document.getElementById('trash-btn');
            const tblResult = document.getElementById('tbl-result');
            const cntTable = document.getElementById('content-table');
            const cntCells = document.getElementsByTagName('td');

            // Event listeners
            toDoButton.addEventListener('click', addToDo);
            completeBtn.addEventListener('click', addComplete);
            impBtn.addEventListener('click', markImp);
            trashBtn.addEventListener('click', deletBtn);


            // Functions


            function addToDo(event) {
                event.preventDefault();

                let newRow = tblResult.insertRow(0);
                let cell1 = newRow.insertCell(0);
                let cell2 = newRow.insertCell(1);
                let cell3 = newRow.insertCell(2);

                cell1.innerHTML = toDoDate.value;
                cell2.innerHTML = toDoInput.value;
                cell3.innerHTML = toDoResp.value;

                selectRow();
            }

            function selectRow() {
                for (i = 0; i < cntCells.length; i++) {
                    cntCells[i].onclick = function () {
                        let indexSel = this.parentNode.rowIndex;
                        let rowsNotSelected = cntTable.getElementsByTagName('tr');
                        for (let row = 0; row < rowsNotSelected.length; row++) {
                            rowsNotSelected[row].style.backgroundColor = "";
                            rowsNotSelected[row].classList.remove('selected');
                        }
                        rowSelected = cntTable.getElementsByTagName('tr')[indexSel];
                        rowSelected.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
                        rowSelected.classList.add('selected');
                    }
                }
            }


            function addComplete() {
                if (rowSelected.classList.contains('selected')) {
                    console.log('hey');
                } else {
                    console.log('no');
                }
            }

            function markImp() {
                console.log('Mark');
            }

            function deletBtn() {
                console.log('DELETE');
            }
        }
        
        init();
```

```html
<form>
        <div>
            <label for="todo-date">Date</label>
            <input type="date" class="todo-date" id="todo-date">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="todo-task">Task</label>
            <input type="text" class="todo-input" id="todo-task">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="todo-responsible">Who is responsible</label>
            <input type="text" class="todo-responsible" id="todo-responsible">
        </div>
        <div>
            <button class="todo-button" id="todo-button">
                <i class="fas fa-plus-square"></i>
                Add todo
            </button>
        </div>
    </form>
    <table class="content-table" id="content-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Task</th>
                <th>Responsible</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="tbl-result" class="tblResult">
            <tr class="tbr-click">
                <td>Date</td>
                <td>Task</td>
                <td>Responsible</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <section>
        <div>
            <button class="complete-btn" id="complete-btn">
                <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
                complte
            </button>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button class="imp-btn" id="imp-btn">
                <i class="fas fa-trash"></i>
                mark
            </button>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button class="trash-btn" id="trash-btn">
                <i class="fas fa-exclamation"></i>
                delete
            </button>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Thank you all. I have to remember about global and local scopes, hopefully, won't make the same mistake again.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** I changed your `selectRow()` function logic in order to make the process much simplier. Now it uses a real CSS class. The code is more cleaner and behavior is the same.

Just use a [`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) since you are adding the class `selected` to the selected row. If none row has the `selected` class, then `selectedRow` will be `null` in the `addComplete` function. Otherwise, will be the selected row.

I also modified your delete and imp icon's button cause you mix them.

```js
// Selectors
const toDoDate = document.getElementById('todo-date');
const toDoInput = document.getElementById('todo-task');
const toDoResp = document.getElementById('todo-responsible');
const toDoButton = document.getElementById('todo-button');
const completeBtn = document.getElementById('complete-btn');
const impBtn = document.getElementById('imp-btn');
const trashBtn = document.getElementById('trash-btn');
const tblResult = document.getElementById('tbl-result');
const cntTable = document.getElementById('content-table');
const cntCells = document.getElementsByTagName('td');

// Event listeners
toDoButton.addEventListener('click', addToDo);
completeBtn.addEventListener('click', addComplete);
impBtn.addEventListener('click', markImp);
trashBtn.addEventListener('click', deleteBtn);


// Functions
function addToDo(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  let newRow = tblResult.insertRow(0);
  let cell1 = newRow.insertCell(0);
  let cell2 = newRow.insertCell(1);
  let cell3 = newRow.insertCell(2);

  cell1.innerHTML = toDoDate.value;
  cell2.innerHTML = toDoInput.value;
  cell3.innerHTML = toDoResp.value;
  
  newRow.addEventListener('click', selectRow);
}

function selectRow() {
  this.classList.toggle('selected');
  document.querySelectorAll('.selected').forEach(item => {
    if (item !== this) {
      item.classList.remove('selected');
    }
  });
}


function addComplete() {
  const rowSelected =  document.querySelector('.selected');
  if (rowSelected) {
    console.log('hey');
  } else {
    console.log('no');
  }
}

function markImp() {
  console.log('Mark');
}

function deleteBtn() {
  console.log('DELETE');
}
```

```css
.selected {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form>
  <div>
    <label for="todo-date">Date</label>
    <input type="date" class="todo-date" id="todo-date">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="todo-task">Task</label>
    <input type="text" class="todo-input" id="todo-task">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="todo-responsible">Who is responsible</label>
    <input type="text" class="todo-responsible" id="todo-responsible">
  </div>
  <div>
    <button class="todo-button" id="todo-button">
      <i class="fas fa-plus-square"></i>
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
<table class="content-table" id="content-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Task</th>
      <th>Responsible</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tbl-result" class="tblResult"></tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td>Date</td>
      <td>Task</td>
      <td>Responsible</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
<section>
  <div>
    <button class="complete-btn" id="complete-btn">
      <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button class="imp-btn" id="imp-btn">
      <i class="fas fa-exclamation"></i>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button class="trash-btn" id="trash-btn">
      <i class="fas fa-trash"></i>
    </button>
  </div>
</section>
```